# Joining image segmentations with dilation/connected components

Tags: mask, image-segmentation, scikit-image

Need an idea on how to join two different labels in a segmentation mask, but only join those that are connected to the target label.

I would like all pixels where the red (target label) and light blue meet to have the same label, and want the separate chunks of light blue pixels on the right to be excluded.

I've tried using skimage.join_segmentation and a few other array operations but I think I'm missing something, would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

[image]